# How to create Vuetify container with nav drawer and re-sizable content next to it?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm having trouble with creating a Vuetify container which will hold a navigation drawer and a re-sizable container (card, row, or any other Vuetify element), that will shrink if the drawer is open or grow when it is closed (similar to Gmail, for example).

There's also a Toolbar at the top of the page, it has to remain always the same size, the drawer has to be only in a container below it.

I tried the following:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" style="background-color: #ccc;">
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid class="align-start px-12 py-12">
        <v-row class="mx-0">
          <v-toolbar flat class="px-6">
            <div class="text-h5 mx-3 primary--text">Messages</div>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-btn
              small
              depressed
              text
              @click="drawer = !drawer"
            >
              toggle drawer
            </v-btn>
          </v-toolbar>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
      <v-container fluid class="align-start px-0 d-flex flex-row">
        <v-navigation-drawer
          v-model="drawer"
          class="mr-2"
          dark
          hide-overlay
        >
          Navigation
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-card flat>card</v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    drawer: true
  })
})
```

That had a very small card and it remained intact when I open/closed the drawer. So I tried to add `width="100%"` property to the card. That made the card take the rest of the place, but it still kept its size when I opened/closed the drawer.

Any help, please? Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/igal-kleiner/pen/RwrYERY) of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to set `:width` prop based in the value of `drawer`...

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire" style="background-color: #ccc;">
    <v-main>
    <v-container fluid class="align-start px-12 py-12">
      <v-row class="mx-0">
        <v-toolbar flat class="px-6">
          <div class="text-h5 mx-3 primary--text">Messages</div>
          <v-spacer />
          <v-btn
            small
            depressed
            text
            @click="drawer = !drawer"
          >
            toggle drawer
          </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
    <v-container fluid class="align-start px-0 d-flex flex-row">
      <v-navigation-drawer
        v-model="drawer"
        class="mr-2"
        dark
        hide-overlay
        :width="drawer?256:0"
      >
        Navigation
      </v-navigation-drawer>
      <v-card flat class="grow">card</v-card>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/J8Yz9Sjy0Q)